# Unable to manage build security

Tags: security

I'm trying to grant build management permissions to some user in the dialog *Team Explorer - Builds/Actions/Security*
[image: TFS Build security window]
When I select any of the groups and click OK, both of the windows close and the group don't get added.

It does not work in both VS2010 and VS2012 and it works in a brand new project collection.
My user is under "[pc]Project Collection Administrators" and "[project]Project Administrators".

**I wonder if is there any project collection permission or some project collection configuration that is blocking me from doing that, any ideas??**.

Also, already tried via tfssecurity.exe:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools>
tfssecurity /a+ BuildAdministration BuildPrivileges ManageBuildResources "domain\user" Allow /collection:http://host:port/collection

TFSSecurity - Team Foundation Server Security Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
The target Team Foundation Server is http://host:port/collection.
Resolving identity "domain\user"...
[U] DOMAIN\user (User name)
Adding the access control entry...
Verifying...

Access Control List on object "BuildPrivileges":
[+] ViewBuildResources                 [pc]\Project Collection Build Administrators
[+] ManageBuildResources               [pc]\Project Collection Build Administrators
[+] UseBuildResources                  [pc]\Project Collection Build Administrators
[+] ViewBuildResources                 [pc]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts
[+] ManageBuildResources               [pc]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts
[+] UseBuildResources                  [pc]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts
[+] ViewBuildResources                 [pc]\Project Collection Administrators
[+] ManageBuildResources               [pc]\Project Collection Administrators
[+] UseBuildResources                  [pc]\Project Collection Administrators
[+] ViewBuildResources                 DOMAIN\User
[+] ManageBuildResources               DOMAIN\User
[+] UseBuildResources                  DOMAIN\User

Done.
```

**Is this the correct permission to grant?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After inserting manually the permission to the user or group it worked again.

```
exec prc_SetAccessControlLists 
@namespaceGuid='33344D9C-FC72-4D6F-ABA5-FA317101A7E9',
@permissionListXML=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><permissions><p t="2cce9a6b-e3a4-4487-97ff-ec8b0669be73" s="120d5125-59a1-4ca1-b4fa-f8f907d348b1" a="1" d="0" /></permissions>',
@inheritListXML=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><inherits></inherits>',
@mergePermissions=0,
@overwriteACL=1,
@separator=N'/',
@writerIdentifier='131E0F97-DE00-4A52-A3E5-78BC975CFFB0'
go
```

Figured it out via trial/error on a new project collection and sql trace.
`permissions@t` must be the TeamFoundationId of the target user on the table ADObjects and `permissions@s` the project_id of tbl_projects

Be aware that it may not be so safe, always make a backup. At least I can use builds again.
Maybe it ocurred because the database was incorrectly detached by the old project collection owner and I had to recover it.